# Recursion and Scope - Assigning a variable conditionally - No Mutable Object Passing

Tags: python, recursion, scope

I have a variation on the following function:

```
from random import randint

def assign_a_value_conditionally():

    threshold = randint(1,4)

    if threshold > 3:

        value = "We made it!"
        return value

    print('before recursion')
    assign_a_value_conditionally()
    print('after recursion')

a = assign_a_value_conditionally()
```

If the function recurses, `a = None`.

If the function doesn't recurse, `a = "We made it!"`

I expected `a` to equal `"We made it!"` in both cases, since it returns with the assignment.

I can see what's happening, but can someone explain **why** it's happening, and **recommend a design pattern** to get the expected, hoped for result?

[Here's a ready to run version](https://repl.it/FwVr/1)

I looked through a bunch of already-asked recursion questions, the ones I saw were about mutable objects, so apologies if this is duplicated somewhere. I don't know what to call it either.

If I took a stab at answering, it's because the value is returning into a nest of function returns, instead of the outside function scope, shown by the print statements.

But I could use some more explanation/discussion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` the result of the recursive call:

```
print('before recursion')
# without return, this statement is without effect
return assign_a_value_conditionally()    
# print('after recursion')  won't be reached
```

If you need to process the recursive result, you must store the result first:

```
res = assign_a_value_conditionally()    
# ... process res
return res
```

Comment: The last `print` is never executed.

Comment: @avysk Yeah, obviously :) time to sleep

Comment: So you broke the intended behavior, I think. It should be something like `res = assign_a_value_conditionally()`, then `print ...`, then `return res`.

Comment: @avysk The `print` statements look like very much like purely for debugging to my eye. And the issue becomes apparent nevertheless and the OP can make adjustments.

Comment: They are, but I guess judging by the question they'll be useful for the topic starter to understand what's going on :)

Comment: Is there a name for this (so I could look it up)? Could you (or anyone) talk through a bit why the return statement makes the nested value pass through? It's not obvious to me that the value will be carried.

Comment: But wow, that definitely makes it work. Thanks. The print statement was for debugging here, but it's good to see the variation..

Comment: @SergeBallesta I included some more nuance.

Comment: @HanLazarus It might not be obvious to the beginner, but without the return -- well -- nothing (None implicitly) is returned. If only the bottom most recursive call returns the string, the upper calls need to do sth with that returned result (return or process) otherwise the recursive call is pointless. That last part does not hold entirely true though for functions that mutate objects or just print some output.

Comment: Thank you, that helps me. I really didn't know that the function would return through the nest (I didn't have anything happening after the bottom return tatement in my actual code), and I didn't know returning the function call carried the namespace.